# Thread-Local storage and iOS

Tags: c++, ios, templates, pthreads, thread-local-storage

My understanding is that iOS does not support `__thread`.  There is, obviously, a way to do this using `pthread_setspecific`.  However, is there already a template class that has implemented this functionality?

I'd ate to re-invent the wheel, especially as it won't be a simple piece of code to write.

Any links would be hugely appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Can you use [`boost::thread_specific_ptr`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html#thread.thread_local_storage.thread_specific_ptr)?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I dunno, possibly.  I wasn't aware of it so its a possibility :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Foundation provides `-[NSThread threadDictionary]`. You can use this to store thread-local Objective-C objects, which could include an `NSValue` wrapping the address of any dynamic storage.

Note that Cocoa is moving towards thread-blind execution of threaded code, where you submit blocks of code to be run on any available system-owned thread. This is the model used by Grand Central Dispatch and the shared `NSOperationQueue`s. Code relying on thread-local storage will not make the best use of this model. See Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more info.

**ETA:** Starting with iOS 5 / OS X 10.7, Grand Central Dispatch gained what you could call queue-local storage via the `dispatch_queue_set_specific`, `dispatch_queue_get_specific`, and `dispatch_get_specific` functions. The setter allows you to supply a destructor function in addition to the value for when you set a new value for the key or when the queue is destroyed. The getter sans queue uses the current queue as context, and will repeat the lookup on the current queue's target queue if the key is not defined on the current queue (similar to how property lookup in a prototypal OO system works).